# Gaining extra security by using longer ciphertext

Tags: security, language-agnostic, encryption

I need to encrypt a plaintext message, using a 256-bit secret key.

The ciphertext may be of any length (not equal to the plaintext length)

Is there an encryption method that can give me extra security when I allow the ciphertext to be longer?

For example: Encoding a 256-bit plaintext into a 8192-bits ciphertext would be more secure than encoding it into a 256-bit ciphertext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically speaking, there's no way to get any extra advantage from encrypting the plaintext into a longer ciphertext.  If I naively try to break your encryption by trying all possible decryption keys, then the length of the ciphertext doesn't matter since I'm still doing a brute-force search over the same key space.  In practice, this might help because it would slow down my attempts to reverse your encryption, but you gain no extra security by having the longer ciphertext.

The reason for this is that the difficulty of breaking a cipher (without attacking the cipher itself) rests in trying to explore the entire space of keys to decrypt.  If your ciphertext is longer but is still decryptable using a 256-bit key, then the space I have to search isn't any bigger than what I started with.

Now, if you make the ciphertext longer by somehow introducing a larger key space (for example, by picking four random keys and encrypting different pieces of the message with each key), then you would indeed gain extra security because the space of keys I have to search when trying to decrypt the message is now substantially larger.

Comment: Your last paragraph is wrong. The key space is not substantially larger by encrypting different pieces of the message with different keys. It is not larger at all.

Comment: @GregS- Can you elaborate on that?  You may very well be right, but I don't understand why.  My understanding is that if I use multiple keys to encode the message, where no one key is sufficient to decode the whole message, you need to search over a larger key space.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: This is dependent on the message in particular, but generally the message will be rather low entropy. Knowing the first half of the message leaks a lot of information about the second half. The benefit from using multiple keys would be minimal. You're better off encrypting the WHOLE message with N keys in sequence.

Also consider that it's only a small computational hindrance. When you're talking 128 or 256 bit encryption, adding two keys only doubles the effort. Making a 129/257 bit encryption total. Plus, if someone is able to break AES256 once, they're probably able to do it twice. :)

Comment: @AltF4- That's a good point, but I was thinking about some system in which the only way to verify that you had decrypted the message correctly would be to use some sort of checksum in the final block that would verify it.  After all, it's hard to ever know if you correctly decrypted a block to the original text or if you just randomly ended up with a wrong key that decrypts to meaningful text.  In that case, you couldn't know if you'd successfully decrypted anything until you had the whole message.  Would this system work in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Adding random padding could be a good idea, it makes sure that the same encrypted message will result in a different ciphertext every time (so that you cannot tell if the messages are the same from looking at the ciphertext).

But 8192 bit seems overkill. An extra 256 for a total of 512 is quite enough.

Adding anything non-random should not improve security at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not in any meaningful way. 256 bits is large enough to use (for example) AES with a 256-bit key. The block size is fixed at 128 bits. AES is one of the most carefully studied ciphers in history, but there's still nothing even approaching a practical attack against it. You do typically want to include an IV with the message, but it's not really part of the encrypted message itself (and it's one extra block in size, so it'd be an extra 128 bits if you used AES).